# Flutter Widget not updating when notifylisters is called

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a `ChangeNotifier` that is fetching data correctly from Firebase Firestore. However my StatefulWidget is not updating when this data is loaded. What am I doing wrong over here?

```
class MyViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  MyViewModel();

  MyModel _myModel;
  FirebaseRepository _firebaseRepository = FirebaseRepository();

  void loadData(String userId) async {
    _myModel =
        await _firebaseRepository.getData(userId);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  getModelName(){
     return _myModel.name;
  }
}
```

and a `ChangeNotifierProvider` setup at the top level of my widget tree

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => MyViewModel(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            home: HomeWithBottomNav(title: 'Bottom Nav Home Page'),
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
              // define the routes
             
              MyPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => MyPage(),
              
            }));
  }
}
```

and a `StatefulWidget` that is trying to listen to the data

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/myPage";

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyPage> {
  MyViewModel myViewModel =
      new MyViewModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    myViewModel.loadData('userId');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<MyViewModel>(context);

    return Consumer<MyViewModel>(
      builder: (context, myViewModel, child) {
        AppBar appBar = AppBar(
            title: Text("Model Name: $myViewModel.getModelName()"), // This is not getting the data fetched from firestore
        );

        SingleChildScrollView singleChildScrollView = SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
        );

        Scaffold scaffold =
            Scaffold(appBar: appBar, body: singleChildScrollView);

        return scaffold;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call myViewModel in this way:

```
Provider.of<myViewModel>(context,listen:false).loadData('userId');
```

but by default you can not call it in initstate because we do not have context there

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have two instances of MyViewModel. one is created here:

```
   ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => MyViewModel(),
          ),
```

and another one here:

```
class _State extends State<MyPage> {
  MyViewModel myViewModel =
      new MyViewModel();
```

the one you call your loadData function is the second one but the one you gain access to from your consumer is the first one.
I suggest you change your stateful widget to a stateless widget, remove the second time you instanciate MyViewModel and instead of calling your desired function from the initsatate, call it from the constructor of MyViewModel.
I hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is two instances, the one providing the state changes, which is the one where your view is registered as a listener, is not the one you call the `loadData` on.

This should work:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async { 
      await Provider.of<MyViewModel>(context, listen: false).loadData('userId');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

You cannot call async methods directly inside the `initState` method, but you can register an async callback to be executed once the Page widget has been mounted, hence the `addPostFrameCallback`. And because it's asynchronous you have access to BuildContext as well.